# Are interfaces only ever implemented by struct data types in Go?

Tags: go

I'm quite new to Go and was looking at Interfaces and their implementations.
All examples I have encountered use `struct{}` to implement any interface.
Is it possible to use any basic type?

Comment: There are plenty of counter examples in the standard library: [json.Number](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Number) is a string type that implements fmt.Stringer, [json.RawMessage](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage) is a slice type that implements json.Marshaler, [http.HandlerFunc](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#HandlerFunc) is a function type that implements http.Handler. The list goes on and on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Method declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations)
>
> A method is a function with a receiver. A method declaration binds an
>   identifier, the method name, to a method, and associates the method
>   with the receiver's base type.
>
> The receiver is specified via an extra parameter section preceding the
>   method name. That parameter section must declare a single non-variadic
>   parameter, the receiver. Its type must be of the form T or *T
>   (possibly using parentheses) where T is a type name. The type denoted
>   by T is called the receiver base type; it must not be a pointer or
>   interface type and it must be defined in the same package as the
>   method. The method is said to be bound to the base type and the method
>   name is visible only within selectors for type T or *T.

---

No. It can be any type other than a pointer or interface type.

---

For example, using `string` as the underlying type,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

type Caser interface {
    Upper() string
    Lower() string
}

type Str string

func (s Str) Upper() string {
    return strings.ToUpper(string(s))
}

func (s Str) Lower() string {
    return strings.ToLower(string(s))
}

func main() {
    str := Str("Forty-Two")
    fmt.Println(str)
    up := str.Upper()
    fmt.Println(up)
    lo := str.Lower()
    fmt.Println(lo)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/9RDRTftqWot

Output:

```
Forty-Two
FORTY-TWO
forty-two
```

---

Comment: Thanks @peterSO, did see that - but couldn't get to make it work with, say, a `string`. Any small example would be really beneficial. Thanks again.

Comment: @snowball: See my revised answer for a `string` example.

Comment: Cheers @peterSO, much appreciated!